# Liquibase autocompletion in eclipse (maven project)

Tags: eclipse, maven, liquibase

I'm trying to have autocompletion for liquibase.

My project works fine with liquibase, but completion doesn't work.

I'm pretty sure it did work last week, after downloading javadoc/sources from liquibase.

Now, whenever I try to have eclipse autocomplete a changelog xml, I can see this:

> Loading reference grammars (sleeping).

It then disappears, and autocompletion doesn't work.

Here is an example changeset header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
     xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">

    <!--  This changelog is used to validate that liquibase works -->
    <changeSet id="1" author="majoros" >
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

**EDIT:** could very well be a proxy issue. I was briefly fully connected to the internet (don't ask...), and it's working now. Still, my coworkers should have it working, too (and I'd like to understand).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse should be able to use autocomplete on XML files that have a descriptor (or whatever it's called).

[Liquibase's wiki](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/databasechangelog) has some examples for database change sets. These all include references to xsd files. These provide information on the structure of the XML.

Sample XML for 1.9:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.9.xsd">
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Sample XML for 2.0:

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Eclipse fetches the xsd files from the web so an Internet connection is required. If you're behind a proxy you have to configure Eclipse to use a proxy. This might explain why it didn't work at first.

To configure a proxy in Eclipse:

Window > Preferences > General > Network connections

Comment: +1 for describing the mechanism, wasn't sure if it should find the xsd in the jar (it's here, but how would it be mapped to the uri?).

Comment: @ymajoros I wouldn't know if Eclipse even has the possibility to look for a xsd file in a jar for this purpose. I don't think that's worth figuring out though. I bet you have more important things to do ;-)

Comment: @ymajoros That's weird. I'm not connected to the Internet all the time, but I never had such problems. I noticed you're not using all the `xsi:schemaLocation`s. Maybe this is the cause of the problem?

Comment: Ok, seems its was my proxy configuration. It works when Eclipse has a connection.